# Rails redirect_to not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have checked the other similar questions, and none have the same issue.  In short after a user logs in, my app redirects to root path.  Should be simple, but for some reason redirect_to is not returning the proper url.  It work fine in development mode. 
I am trying to learn how do setup the production mode. So I have a tiny app with nothing but a login/logout at, grah.ddns.net  When I do a redirect_to to the root_url I get the following in the address box of my browser:

> "http://grah.ddns.net, grah.ddns.net"

I have no idea why redirect_to would return such a string.

Here is my controller code:

```
def login
  user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
  if user.present?
    @user = user.authenticate(params[:password])
    if @user.present?
      session[:userID] = @user.id
      session[:userName] = params[:name]
    end
  end
  // responds with "http://grah.ddns.net, grah.ddns.net
  redirect_to root_url  

end

def logout
  session.delete(:userID) if session[:userID].present?
  session.delete(:userName) if session[:userName].present?
  // Which should I use root_path or root_url?
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

and here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'main#index'

  get 'main/index'

  post 'session/login'
  get 'session/logout'

end
```

I see nothing here that should cause what I am getting. The only thing I found remotely connected to this is:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Which is true in development mode, and it works. What part of doing production mode am I missing???  Half tempted to just run in development mode...sheesh.

Comment: Would you please share your routes file?

Comment: add routes file to question.

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect_to `root_path` instead ur root_url. It will redirect you to *root 'main#index'*

_URL is better for displaying the url to outside sources. Within your app, _PATH works fine as it is already linked to your current url. No need to repeat..

The path will just return '/', whereby the url will return full url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

`root "main#index"`

at the end in route.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that with

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

all redirect_to statements have to be fully qualified domain names. Using a FQDN has fixed my problem.